# Yearless between date check with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find date comes in intervals or not without a year.

Example:

Date_intervals = '07/01~07/10'

if I want to check 07/05 between Date_intervals then true else false.

how I can able to find this with Ruby?

Comment: You can write `b, e = '07/01~07/10'.split('~'); '07/05' >= b && '07/05' <= e #=> true`. You will find `b #=> '07/01'` and `e #=> '07/10'`. Strings are compared with [String#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). That doc explains how the comparison is done.

Comment: Would `'12/20~01/15'` (Dec 20 – Jan 15) be a valid interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your function:

```
def is_between(x,y)
    a,b=x.split('~',2)
    y>=a && y<=b 
end
```

Testing:

```
irb(main):009:0> is_between('07/01~07/10','07/05')
=> true
irb(main):010:0> is_between('07/01~07/10','07/11')
=> false
```

This **requires** that the dates 1) have leading `0` for single digit days and months and 2) use the same format exactly since this is based on string comparisons.

Comment: Thank you for your response this works fine with all conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option that rely on date comparison (not string comparison).
It can be easily adapted to other date formats:

```
def in_interval?(string_date, string_date_interval)
  date = string_date.to_date
  date_interval = string_date_interval.split('~').map(&:to_date)
  Range.new(*date_interval).cover?(date)
end

in_interval?('07/10', '07/01~07/10')
```

If you need another date format you can use `Date.strptime(string_date, '%m/%d')` instead of `to_date`.

You can find the list of the directives here:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.7/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#strptime-method

Comment: This breaks if one of the provided dates is 02/29 and it's not currently a leap year.

Comment: I think that is the expected behaviour. If you don't specify the year, it means that you refer to the current year. If there is no `02/29` you get an exception `ArgumentError: invalid date` as you would for a that doesn't exist (for example `01/32`).

Comment: I'm not so sure. For example maybe the question is asking about how to code something for yearly recurring events.

Comment: Thank you for your response but this will not work for leap year. I think the above string solution works in all conditions.